# python: extract the emoticon text from Japanese twitter text with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, twitter, emoticons

I took the following regex to extract the emoticon text from the Japanese twitter with python.

```
// this is for extracting number, character, Japanese
text2 = r'[0-9A-Za-zぁ-んァ-ン一-龥]'  

non_text = r'[^0-9A-Za-zぁ-んァ-ン一-龥]'
// this is for extracting text that are allowed in Japanese emoticons
allow_text = r'[ovっつ゜ニノ三二]'
hw_kana = r'[ｦ-ﾟ]'
open_branket = r'[\(∩　（]'
close_branket = r'[\)∩　）]'
arround_face = r'(?:' + non_text + '|' + allow_text + ')*'
face = r'(?!(?:' + text2 + '|' + hw_kana + '){3,}).{3,}'
face_string = arround_face + open_branket + face + close_branket +    
              arround_face
p_face = re.compile(face_string)

string1 = 'ふう。お腹いっぱい( ´•౪•`), 試験頑張るぞ＼＼\\ ٩( ‘ω’ )و //／／'
string2 = '心の相談は　メール　tiknathan@mail.goo.ne.jp までご連絡ください'
string3 = 'ドーピング系浪人生(n=1)'
string4 = '横浜は関内にある「　ＢＡＹ　らっきょ　」に初訪問してまいりました関東スープカレーブームの火付け役となったお店の「　人気ＮＯ.１　チキンカレー　」をいただきました(´∀｀人)'
string5 = '鳥取県倉吉市   倉吉農業高校  3年食品科 （音楽部・茶道部）    AKB48大ファン高校生！まゆゆ、中野郁海ちゃん神推し    m0326w｡♥｡･ﾟ♡ﾟ･｡♥｡i0820n～現在♥大好きだよ♥       AKBファンの方はフォローお願いします^-^  \n\n来春から新社会人・・・の予定(´・ω・｀)   '
string6 = 'うわ。。(-_-;)授業。運動会はなくなると？'
string7 = '毎月泊まっちゃえ♡親孝行*\(^o^)/*でも出来る時しとかないとだよ(o^^o)'

emoj1 = p_face.findall(string1)
emoj2 = p_face.findall(string2)
emoj3 = p_face.findall(string3)
emoj4 = p_face.findall(string4)
emoj5 = p_face.findall(string5)
emoj6 = p_face.findall(string6)
emoj7 = p_face.findall(string6)


print(emoj1)
print(emoj2)
print(emoj3)
print(emoj4)
print(emoj5)
print(emoj6)
print(emoj7)
```

but the result is following:

```
1.  ['( ´•౪•`), 試験頑張るぞ＼＼\\ ٩( ‘ω’ )و']
2.  ['\u3000メール\u3000']
3.  ['(n=1)']
4.  ['「\u3000ＢＡＹ\u3000'] 
5.  ['(´・ω・｀)   ']
6.  ['。。(-_-;)']
```

But there are some issues:
   The string1, actually there are two emoticons:

```
    ( ´•౪•`) and ＼＼\\ ٩( ‘ω’ )و //／／
```

but the result just show one emoticon which two emoticons together with other Japanese text. I just want to the following list included two emoticons:

```
[ '( ´•౪•`)',' ＼＼\\ ٩( ‘ω’ )و //／／']
```

secondly, the string5 actually the ♥｡･ﾟ♡ﾟ･｡♥｡ and ^-^ are also emoticon, but these emotion can't be extracted by the answered regex.

In addition, there is no emoticon text(　メール　 and (n=1) ['「 ＢＡＹ ']are not emoticons) in the string2, string3 and string 4. but the regex pattern has extracted these text. Could you give me you hand how to solve this, thanks! 
please check the Japanese emoticon: http://kaomojiya.com/kao/?other/line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regular expression should match what you want

```
expr = '[^0-9A-Za-zぁ-んァ-ン一-龥ovっつ゜ニノ三二]*'       +  // [1]
           '[\(∩　（]'                                    +  // [2]
               '[^0-9A-Za-zぁ-んァ-ン一-龥ｦ-ﾟ\)∩　）]*'    +  // [3]
           '[\)∩　）]'                                    +  // [4]
        '[^0-9A-Za-zぁ-んァ-ン一-龥ovっつ゜ニノ三二]*'         // [5]
```

You cant try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/iRY5ZL/1).

It starts by matching potential *special* characters (anything except numbers, romaji, hiragana, katakana and kanji, plus *special kanas*) `[1]` as you do. Then, it matches what you called `open_branket` `[2]`, and then any non kanji, non number, etc. **and non `close_branket`** `[3]`. Finally, it matched the end of the emoji the same way you do with `[4]` and `[5]`

---

**EDIT**

```
string4 = ...
string5 = ...
```

The problem with `string4` is that the characters `ＢＡＹ` differ from `BAY`. The seconds one are the usual ASCII characters `0x42`, `0x41` and `0x59` while the first ones are [unicode characters](http://unicode-table.com/en/FF21/) between `0xff21` and `0xff3a`. You can just add them to the list of rejected characters (`[3]`). You might also want to add their [lower case version](http://unicode-table.com/en/FF41/) from `ａ` (`0xff41`) to `ｚ` (`0xff5a`) as well as the corresponding digits, from `0xff10` to `0xff19`
You might be interested by reading [this page about fullwidth and halfwidth](http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/halfwidth-and-fullwidth-forms/).

The problem with `string5` is that those emoji do not contain any open/close character as you defined them. For the first emoji, this can be solved by adding `。` to the list of opening character if this is acceptable. However, it doesn't solve the problem of `^-^`.

I would suggest to change the strategy. Something that l[ooks to work not too bad](https://regex101.com/r/NtOYlv/2) is to choose a set of common characters that appears in usual text (let's call it `C`) and a subset of `C` that might appear in emojis (let's call it `S`) and a number `x`. Then you can build the following regular expression :

```
(?:C*)(?P<match>(?:[^C]|S){x,})(?:C*)
```

This expression will match a "regular" text in a non capturing group followed by a captured sequence of at least `x` "non regular" characters or characters from your subset `S` captured in a group named `match` followed by any "regular" text non captured.

Investigating the unicode table, I defined `C` as the following set

```
\u4e00-\u9fff      => CJK Unified Ideographs
\u3400-\u4dbf      => CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A
\uf900-\ufaff      => CJK Compatibility Ideographs
\u3040-\u309f      => Hiragana
\u30a0-\u30ff      => Katakana
\u3000-\u303f      => "CJK Symbol and punctuation"
\uff21-\uff3a      => fullwidth A to Z
\uff41-\uff5a      => fullwidth a to z
\uff10-\uff19      => Fullwidth 0 to 9
\uff00-\uff0e      => Fullwidth form of some punctuation characters
A-Z                => ASCII A to Z
a-z                => ASCII a to z
0-9                => ASCII numbers
@.,;!\? 　～♥\     => other punctuation characters
```

And `S` as `[人・;皿。゜°うぅ]` and `x` to `3` but you need to inspect more the set of japanese emoji to refine it.

For more information

- [CJK Unified Ideographs](http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/cjk-unified-ideographs/)
- [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A](http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/cjk-unified-ideographs-extension-a/)
- [CJK Compatibility Ideographs](http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/cjk-compatibility-ideographs/)
- [Hiragana](http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/hiragana/)
- [Katakana](http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/katakana/)
- [Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms](http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/halfwidth-and-fullwidth-forms/)
- [CJK Symbol and punctuation](http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/cjk-symbols-and-punctuation/)

This lead to the following regular expression

```
(?:[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DBF\uF900-\ufaff\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\u3000-\u303f\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\uff10-\uff19\uff00-\uff0eA-Za-z0-9@.,;!\? 　～♥\\]*)(?P<match>(?:[^\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u380f\uF900-\ufaff\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\u3000-\u303f\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\uff10-\uff19A-Za-z0-9\r\n]|[人・;皿。゜°うぅ]){3,})(?:[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DBF\uF900-\ufaff\u3040-\u309f\u30a0-\u30ff\u3000-\u303f\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\uff10-\uff19A-Za-z0-9@.,; 　～♥\\]*)
```

As a conclusion I would say it's not really possible to match every Japanese emoji with one regular expression as they don't follow any well defined pattern. Moreover, they look to include and sometimes end with regular text. For example `(｡´-д-)疲れた。。` taken from your link. Another solution like a database of emojis might be interesting to investigate

Comment: I really thanks for your comments @Thomas Wilmotte. I am confirming it, and I will report the result.

Comment: there are some issues after I confirmed it.

Comment: 1. I have updated the question which added a new string4, please read it, and I found if there are two or three spaces after '。' or the emoticons(the space will be \u3000). and it will be wrong to think this is emoticon.

Comment: 2. I have added string5 also, please notice it.

Comment: hi @Thomas Wilmotte, if possible, could you send me your email or twitter account to communicate this issue in detail, thanks.

Comment: @tktktk0711 I edited the answer, please have a look and comment here if you need more info

Comment: @tktktk0711 I saw you added more strings while I was editing my post. If you add `o` to the set `S` and set `x` to `4`, these strings works well with the new strategy

Comment: thanks @Thomas Wilmotte for your comments. I have solved 「　ＢＡＹ　らっきょ　」issue, Firstly, I replace '「　' and '　」' with '', then used your regex is ok. But the string7, how to extract the (^o^) in the string7

Comment: @tktktk0711 It will work if you accept `o` inside your `face` part. This can be donne by replacing `[^0-9A-Za-zぁ-んァ-ン一-龥ｦ-ﾟ\)∩　）]*` by `(?:[^0-9A-Za-zぁ-んァ-ン一-龥ｦ-ﾟ\)∩　）]|[o])*` however, `(o)` will match too. Maybe you'll want to force the number or characters between your open/close characters.
If you use the seond strategy, you can add `o` to the set `S` and set `x` to `4`

Comment: thanks for comments @Thomas Wilmotte. I am confirming it. I will contact you after I have done.